# Split string after : and before?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have  a long string like this :

```
je!tress:e?tu!tress:es?il!tress:e?nous!tress:ons?vous!tress:ez?ils!tress:ent?
```

i want to split the string after : and before ? . So  this i want to have into array :

```
{e,es,e,ons,ez,en}
```

i know that i can do this:

```
 NSArray *subStrings = [stringToChange componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
```

but it's not enough.
How can i do this ,please? Any help will be appreciate !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option could be to use [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html) class.

Using this pattern:

```
\\:([^\?]+)\?
```

Sample code:

```
NSString *sample  = @"je!tress:e?tu!tress:es?il!tress:e?nous!tress:ons?vous!tress:ez?ils!tress:ent?";
NSString *pattern = @"\\:([^\?]+)\?";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];


NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:sample
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [sample length])];
if(!error && [matches count] > 0) {
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSRange matchRange = [match range];
        NSLog(@"%@" ,[sample substringWithRange:matchRange]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2015-07-03 12:16:39.037 TestRegex[3479:48301] :e
2015-07-03 12:16:39.039 TestRegex[3479:48301] :es
2015-07-03 12:16:39.039 TestRegex[3479:48301] :e
2015-07-03 12:16:39.040 TestRegex[3479:48301] :ons
2015-07-03 12:16:39.040 TestRegex[3479:48301] :ez
2015-07-03 12:16:39.040 TestRegex[3479:48301] :ent
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSScanner` to parse through the string, searching for `:` and `?` tags. You can discard the text you don't want and capture the parts you do (based on which tag you find) and add them to an array.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
  NSString *names = @"je!tress:e?tu!tress:es?il!tress:e?nous!tress:ons?vous!tress:ez?ils!tress:ent?";
NSArray *namesarray = [names componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSMutableArray *desiredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
[namesarray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
NSRange rangeofsign = [(NSString*)obj rangeOfString:@"?"];
NSString *extractedName = [(NSString*)obj substringToIndex:rangeofsign.location];
[desiredArray addObject:extractedName];
 }];
NSLog(@"%@",desiredArray);
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Index 9223372036854775807 out of bounds; string length 8'

Comment: you need some workaround code, it's not tested code.

Answer (score 1):

To be simpler, you could try the following code:

```
NSString *string = @"je!tress:e?tu!tress:es?il!tress:e?nous!tress:ons?vous!tress:ez?ils!tress:ent?";
NSArray *firstArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *newString in firstArray) {
    NSArray *tempArray = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
    if ([tempArray count] > 1) {
        [finalArray addObject:[tempArray firstObject]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",finalArray);
```

Comment: ii get the same string in array